# Not Finding Element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am new to ruby development using Selenium. But I am familiar with Java with Selenium. Now 
my concern is I started developing the code in Ruby using Selenium.I am not able to find and click on the login button on one of the website.

I got the login id as when I am doing XPATH as

```
.//*[@id='index']/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/button
```

How to code this in ruby. Normally I am seeing the code as

```
driver.find_element(:id,"email")
```

Thanks in advance for your answers

Regards,
Sudhakar KS

Comment: Have you looked at watir or capybara as an api layer ontop of webdriver? It makes things much nicer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, your *XPATH* will work. Here is a Ruby equivalent code :

```
string = ".//*[@id='index']/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/button"
driver.find_element(:xpath, string).click
```

[`find_element`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method) takes as its first arguments :-

`:class`, `:class_name`, `:css`, `:id`, `:link_text`, `:link`, `:partial_link_text`, `:name`, `:tag_name`, `:xpath`.

Comment: Thanks Arup and Jeff for your answers. It worked for me.